# Opencart MySQL Response Very Slowly

Tags: opencart

I am using Opencart.

10M Product SQL Table

SQL responsible very slowly.

My server info;
48 CPU
64GB Memory

PHP 7.3
Mariadb 10.3
Nginx + PHP-FPM

SELECT p.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM oc_review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT price FROM oc_product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM oc_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special FROM oc_product_to_category p2c LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '0' AND p2c.category_id = '18' GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC LIMIT 0,48

Comment: which is actual version of opencart ?

Comment: define('VERSION', '2.3.0.2');

Comment: Yes I will check

Comment: add index in p.sort_order column